# How to open a new window after user login (login controls)?

Tags: asp.net

A new popup window opens but it is redirected to the login page and the base page also fails to login by showing in-correct password. Requirement : we need a popup window after login without any BACK Button on the browser.

```
<asp:Content ID="LoginContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="LoginContent" runat="server">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="LoginUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel Width="100%" runat="server" ID="LoginPanel" HorizontalAlign="Center" DefaultButton="MainLogin$LoginButton">
                <asp:Label ID="LoginMessageValue" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Login RememberMeSet="false" ID="MainLogin" OnLoggedIn="MainLogin_LoggedIN"  OnAuthenticate="Login_Click" runat="server" SkinID="standardLoginObject" EnableTheming="True"
                  TextBoxStyle-Width="150px" DisplayRememberMe="false">
                </asp:Login>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub Login_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'OnAuthenticate = "Login_Click"
        ' ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "error", "window.open('~/workflow/Worklist2.aspx', 'mywindow', 'status=1,toolbar=0');", True)
        Try
            Common.UserObject = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(MainLogin.UserName)

            Dim _userID As Integer = Common.UserObject.ProviderUserKey
            Common.InitializeSession(_userID, nameSpaceURI)
            Dim _role() As String = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(Common.UserObject.UserName)
            If _role.Length = 0 Then
                Common.ClearSession()
                Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LoginPath"), False)
                'MainLogin.FailureText = "Please contact the customer service to review your account setup."
                'ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, "Error", "alert('Please contact the customer service to review your account setup.')", True)
            End If
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "success", "window.open('../workflow.aspx', 'mywindow', 'status=1,toolbar=0'); window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight); window.moveTo(0,0); ", True)
        Catch ex As Exception
            SaveException(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your real problem is that you are trying to show an error page which also requires the user to be authenticated to see it.

you should move your error page  to a location that is publicly visible.

You can specify this behaviour in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="~/errorpage.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```